# How static and normal methods are stored in memory in java?

Tags: java, static, heap-memory

How the static methods and normal methods are stored in memory? If its a heap structure how the methods are associated with the classes and objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read much more about the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), its bytecode, and its [class loaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader).

You could download and read the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/jvms7.pdf).

In practice, JVMs are using [JIT compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques on the bytecode.

In principle, JVMs load  classes (e.g. in `.class` files)  containing bytecode (and other data).

A Java class is represented by some structure containing something similar to a [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) which (in theory) associate function bytecode to method names.